# Change the class of an application during runtime?

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, application-server

I would like to change the class while the application is active on the application server. I am using JBoss 5 and JBoss 7.

- Can we change the class at runtime?
- Otherwise, will I do undeploy and redeploy?
- What do I need to configure in JBoss?
- Which Application Server supports that feature?
- To get this feature will need to write custom `ClassLoader`?

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to change the current ClassLoader to load your class ?
I think in that case you cannot change it on the fly. Instead you can use a CustomClassLoader to load a new class runtime.

Comment: You should be somewhat more explicit on what you are trying to achieve. Undeploy/deploy is certainly one way of replacing a class of your application, it doesn't sound like that is exactly what you want to do though. What are your constraints?

Comment: what about performing this upgrade at a less busy time.

Comment: You could try [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/), or its [LiveRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/liverebel/) cousin, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

- Can we change the class at runtime?
  Actually, you can unload the old class and load a new one.
- Otherwise, will I do undeploy and redeploy?
  You can do it dinamically, without needing to redeploy. However, you are probably aware that JBoss and most of application servers nowadays support hot deploy, what might be what you want:
  A_Quick_Tour-Hot-deployment_of_services_in_JBoss.html">https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Getting_Started_Guide/The_JBoss_Server_A_Quick_Tour-Hot-deployment_of_services_in_JBoss.html
  Be aware, however, that how deploy is very different from "changing a class". It's much more than that, read the docs or write a new question if it's the case.
- What do I need to configure in JBoss?
  Nothing, you should do it in your code. Also, you will need to create some code to load the up to date jar file from wherever you want to put the up to date version. 
  If hot deploy is enough for you, you can check what be configured in the link above.
- Which Application Server supports that feature?
  Custom class loading can be done in any application server, it's a feature of Java Standard Edition, you only depend on your ability to code. Some application servers, like JBoss, have already some built in features to help you in this task.
- To get this feature will need to write custom ClassLoader?
  Unless the application server features to dinamically load modules when you change then are enough for your needs, yes, you will need to implement custom classloaders. By using classloaders, you can load newer versions of a class the way you choose, from anyware. You could load the newer version of your class from your database of from a website, for example.